# Why I get indentation errors with nested let/guard block

Tags: haskell

I'm in the middle of writing a transpose function as an exercise for real world haskell. however, I'm deeply frustrated as somehow haskell fails to parse(or I fail to write properly write) my code.

here's the problem:

```
transpose :: [Char] -> [Char]
transpose x = 
        let splitted = lines x
            transposed = tpose splitted
            tpose :: [String] -> [String]
            tpose xs 
                | null xs = []
                | all null xs = []
                | otherwise = let
                    safeHead "" = ''
                 >> safeHead x = head x
                    safeTail "" = ""
                    safeTail x = tail x
                        in (map safeHead xs):(tpose (map safeTail xs)) 


        in unlines transposed
```

the parse error is at `>>`. whole message is `parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched bracked)`.

I even tried rewriting the code without let, like:

```
        tpose :: [String] -> [String]
        tpose xs 
            | null xs = []
            | all null xs = []
            | otherwise = (map safeHead xs):(tpose (map safeTail xs)) 
                    where
                        safeHead "" = ''
                        safeHead x = head x
                        safeTail "" = ""
                        safeTail x = tail x
```

but still can't fix that indentation error. How can I write nested let/while/guards properly?

Comment: `''` is not valid syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is on the previous line - `''` is not a valid character:

```
                    safeHead "" = ''
                    safeHead x = head x
```

Comment: how do I write empty `Char` ?

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty `Char` value. When defining a function `[a] -> a` you need to decide on a default value to return for the empty list.

Comment: @thkang You should look into `Maybe`.

Comment: for now, I don't need Maybes here.. What I needed was just a whitespace `' '`. I understand that there is no such empty `Char` in haskell.

Comment: @thkang I would suggest pattern matching on `(x:xs)` and `[]` in the `transpose` function instead of using those helper functions.

Comment: @DavidYoung How do I write predicate `all null xs` as a pattern matching with guard?

Comment: @thkang: You wouldn't really replace that part with a pattern match (not directly, anyway). You could have something like: `transpose [] = []; transpose lst = case lst of [] -> ...; (x:xs) | all null xs -> ...; | otherwise -> ...`

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, the syntax error was actually the empty character `''` in `safeHead`.

Let's refactor a little. `safeHead` and `tpose` don't use any data from `transpose`, so can be uninlined for clarity

```
safeHead "" = ' '
safeHead x = head x
safeTail "" = ""
safeTail x = tail x
```

`tpose` can use pattern matching and we can get rid of a couple of brackets:

```
tpose :: [String] -> [String]
tpose [] = [] 
tpose xs 
    | all null xs = []
    | otherwise = map safeHead xs : tpose (map safeTail xs)
```

Leaving just

```
transpose :: [Char] -> [Char]
transpose x = 
        let splitted = lines x
            transposed = tpose splitted
        in unlines transposed
```

Now it becomes apparent that all the lets in `transpose` are just doing `lines`, then `tpose` then `unlines`, so we should use composition for that:

```
transpose :: [Char] -> [Char]
transpose = unlines . tpose . lines
```